# How to find the first row (date) of the series of 5 or more rows (date) with below 0 value

Tags: r, if-statement, time-series, logical-operators, logical-or

I have average temperature data with date below. I wanted to find the date which is the beginning of consistent below or above 0 Celsius in series of at least 5 days.

```r
  date_short mean.temp
1 2018-05-18  17.54
2 2018-05-19  19.45
3 2018-05-20  22.31
4 2018-05-21  13.26
5 2018-05-22  10.29
6 2018-05-23  15.06
```

I have used following scripts and found out how many days are below 0 and what rows meet the criteria of below 0 temperature. It shows that there are total of 147 days with below 0 degree temperature and in which row the below 0 temperature observed. From that I can see 161st date is the first day with below 0 temperature, but it is not what I wanted, because it is not the first date of the series of at least 5 days with below or above 0 degree. Instead I want R to return 170th day as it is the beginning of the series of at least 5 days with below or above 0 degree.

```
length(which(d.mean$mean.temp <= 0))
[1] 147
which(d.mean$mean.temp <= 0)
  [1] 161 162 166 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195
 [30] 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224
 [59] 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253
 [88] 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282
[117] 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 307 308 309 310 313 314 315 316 317
[146] 318 324
```

How can I do it in R. I can do it manually, but I have to find such date for many columns.
In excel, the function would be something like below.

```
IF(B2<0, IF(B3<0, IF(B4<0, IF(B5<0, IF(B6<0,A2,""),""),""),""),"")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with `tidyversere` and `zoo` would be the following. You can use `rollapply` to find 5 temperatures less than zero, setting those as `TRUE`. As a rolling window, it will flag those dates that are followed by four additional (consecutive) dates with temperatures below zero. To filter out dates where these series take place, look at transition from FALSE to TRUE.

**Edit**: If you have multiple columns of temperatures, and want to apply this approach to each column of temperatures, you can use `pivot_longer` and `group_by` first. Example now includes 3 columns of temperatures.

```
set.seed(126)

library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = "temp", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  mutate(start = rollapply(value < 0, width = 5, all, align = "left", fill = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(start & !lag(start, default = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::select(date, temp) %>%
  arrange(temp, date)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   temp [3]
  date       temp  
  <date>     <chr> 
1 2020-01-10 temp_A
2 2020-01-16 temp_A
3 2020-01-22 temp_A
4 2020-01-05 temp_B
5 2020-01-22 temp_B
6 2020-01-01 temp_C
7 2020-01-23 temp_C
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2020/01/01"), as.Date("2020/02/01"), "days"),
  temp_A = sample(c(-10:2), 32, replace = TRUE),
  temp_B = sample(c(-10:2), 32, replace = TRUE),
  temp_C = sample(c(-10:2), 32, replace = TRUE)
)

         date temp_A temp_B temp_C
1  2020-01-01     -9     -8     -6
2  2020-01-02     -1      1     -9
3  2020-01-03     -6     -7     -4
4  2020-01-04      0      1     -9
5  2020-01-05      2     -8     -3
6  2020-01-06     -4     -3      0
7  2020-01-07     -1     -3      1
8  2020-01-08      2     -3      0
9  2020-01-09      1     -6      1
10 2020-01-10     -1     -7     -1
11 2020-01-11     -2     -4     -6
12 2020-01-12     -8     -2      1
13 2020-01-13     -7      1     -5
14 2020-01-14     -3     -2     -7
15 2020-01-15      0      0     -8
16 2020-01-16     -1     -4    -10
17 2020-01-17     -4     -1      2
18 2020-01-18     -6      1     -9
19 2020-01-19     -5     -7     -5
20 2020-01-20     -4     -6      0
21 2020-01-21      2      0     -6
22 2020-01-22     -1     -3      0
23 2020-01-23     -4     -7     -3
24 2020-01-24     -2     -7     -5
25 2020-01-25    -10     -1    -10
26 2020-01-26     -5     -6     -6
27 2020-01-27     -3    -10     -1
28 2020-01-28     -8     -5      1
29 2020-01-29      0      1     -2
30 2020-01-30      2     -9     -6
31 2020-01-31    -10     -4     -1
32 2020-02-01      2    -10     -4
```

Comment: But what about multiple columns? Can I apply same logic for multiple columns, and insert those dates to the end of respective columns without repeating one by one

Comment: @Vandka Please see edited answer. If I understand correctly, you have multiple columns of temperatures, is that right? If so, you can use `pivot_longer` and `group_by` to apply this approach to multiple columns. Please let me know if this is what you had in mind. (If it isn't, clarify what your starting dataset looks like, as well as what your desired end result should look like.)

Comment: Yes, I have multiple columns of temperature data. I have applied the modified script and it works.

Answer (score 4):

The `rle` (run length encoding) function of base R is enough to do this, e.g.

```r
# sample data
set.seed(47)
df <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date("1970-01-01"), length = 500, by = "days"),
    temp = rnorm(500)
)

runs <- rle(df$temp < 0)

df[(cumsum(runs$lengths) - runs$lengths + 1)[runs$values & runs$lengths >= 5], ]
#>           date       temp
#> 25  1970-01-25 -0.3264668
#> 270 1970-09-27 -0.5443173
#> 350 1970-12-16 -0.8436569
#> 356 1970-12-22 -1.2768785
#> 370 1971-01-05 -1.4122783
#> 431 1971-03-07 -0.4711361
#> 454 1971-03-30 -0.9901146
```

To break that down a little, look at the component parts:

```r
runs
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:235] 3 1 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 1 ...
#>   values : logi [1:235] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...

# start index of each run
head((cumsum(runs$lengths) - runs$lengths + 1), 20)
#>  [1]  1  4  5  6  8  9 12 14 15 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 30 33 34 37

# runs where temp < 0 and length >= 5
head(runs$values & runs$lengths >= 5, 20)
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# together, indices of first rows which satisfy the conditions
(cumsum(runs$lengths) - runs$lengths + 1)[runs$values & runs$lengths >= 5]
#> [1]  25 270 350 356 370 431 454
```

Comment: But what about multiple columns? Can I apply same logic for multiple columns, and insert those dates to the end of respective columns without repeating one by one

Comment: That could mean a number of things, but generally yes, you can `lapply` this across multiple temperature columns or use multiple columns in determining runs or any other number of variants.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (maybe less elegant) you can use `rleid` function from `data.table` in combination with `dplyr` package.

Briefly, you convert your temperature into 0 and 1 depending if they are below or above 0. Then, `rleid` will calculate the length of each consecutive sequences of 1 or 0 and attribute a number for each sequence. You can group by this number and see the length of each sequence, find the minimum date for each sequence and filter for sequence superior to 4 and you get a list of temperature below or above 0 and when they have start.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
Result_DF <- df %>% 
  mutate(Above0 = ifelse(temp > 0,1,0)) %>% # Compute temperature above 0
  mutate(Seq_ID = rleid(Above0)) %>% 
  group_by(Seq_ID) %>%
  mutate(Length_seq = n()) %>%
  filter(Length_seq > 4) %>%
  mutate(Date_Min = min(date)) %>%
  distinct(Date_Min, Above0, Length_seq, Seq_ID)

# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   Seq_ID [18]
   Date_Min   Above0 Length_seq Seq_ID
   <date>      <dbl>      <int>  <int>
 1 2018-02-04      1          6     23
 2 2018-02-14      1          6     25
 3 2018-02-28      1          6     31
 4 2018-03-09      1          9     33
 5 2018-04-06      1          5     47
 6 2018-04-30      1          5     59
 7 2018-06-19      1          5     83
 8 2018-06-30      1          6     87
 9 2018-07-14      1          6     93
10 2018-07-25      1          9     97
11 2018-08-21      1          5    107
12 2018-09-08      1          6    117
13 2018-09-25      1         10    125
14 2018-10-15      1          7    131
15 2018-10-23      1          7    133
16 2018-11-23      0          5    148
17 2018-12-05      1          6    155
18 2018-12-24      1          5    163
```

There is probably faster and more elegant way to do that (@Ben's answer is pretty straightforward) but it's just an another option.

---

**EDIT: Improved code (Thank to @allistaire's comment)**

Thank to @allistaire's comment, you can go much way quickly by doing:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(run = data.table::rleid(temp > 0)) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 5) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

**Reproducible example**

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 temp = sample(-15:25, 365, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Same logic, more concise: `df %>% group_by(run = data.table::rleid(temp < 0)) %>% filter(temp < 0, n() >= 5) %>% slice(1)`. That assumes dates are in order; if not add an `arrange` before `slice` or swap the slicing for `summarise(date = min(date))`

Comment: Thank you for the trick to get it simpler. However, it seems that your code gives me two more sequences than mine.

Comment: Got it, it is because of the sign for detecting above or below 0. Thanks again for your nice tip, I will add it to my answer

Comment: Sorry, you need the extra condition in the filter to check `temp < 0` (or the reverse, if that's what you're trying to find); the one in `rleid` won't filter out runs that are all positive or all negative.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out and I replace the sign and get the same results that with my long succession of pipes. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rle`.

```
LEN <- 5
rrl <- rle(+(dat$temp < 0))
(bel.0 <- 
  which(c(NA, diff(rep(suppressWarnings(rrl$lengths*(1:0)), rrl$lengths) >= LEN)) == 1))
# [1]   4  21 306 384 417 427
```

We suppress the warnings that are caused by the fact that the `1-0` period can be incomplete.

### Check:

```
dat$minus <- 0
dat$minus[bel.0] <- 1

head(dat, 30)
#          date   temp minus
# 1  2017-12-01 -14.03     0
# 2  2017-12-02  17.33     0
# 3  2017-12-03  20.02     0
# 4  2017-12-04 -21.28     1
# 5  2017-12-05 -23.49     0
# 6  2017-12-06 -13.04     0
# 7  2017-12-07 -19.27     0
# 8  2017-12-08 -18.76     0
# 9  2017-12-09  26.44     0
# 10 2017-12-10  10.14     0
# 11 2017-12-11  -6.05     0
# 12 2017-12-12 -19.10     0
# 13 2017-12-13  -4.88     0
# 14 2017-12-14 -19.19     0
# 15 2017-12-15   6.95     0
# 16 2017-12-16 -19.07     0
# 17 2017-12-17  -2.02     0
# 18 2017-12-18   4.96     0
# 19 2017-12-19 -15.18     0
# 20 2017-12-20   5.80     0
# 21 2017-12-21 -24.17     1
# 22 2017-12-22 -23.51     0
# 23 2017-12-23 -10.26     0
# 24 2017-12-24  -7.91     0
# 25 2017-12-25  -7.65     0
# 26 2017-12-26   8.66     0
# 27 2017-12-27  -9.71     0
# 28 2017-12-28 -15.09     0
# 29 2017-12-29 -28.49     0
# 30 2017-12-30 -22.01     0
```

---

*Data*

```
set.seed(666)
temp <- sample(-(3e3):3e3, 5e2, replace=TRUE) / 1e2
dat <- data.frame(date=as.Date(seq(temp) + 1.75e4), temp)
```